# How does PS1 Backwards Compatibility work on the PS2?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, ps2

How does PS1 Backwards Compatibility work on the PS2?

I remember someone saying that the console would reset into a PS1 only mode, but I'm not sure if this was true.

Comment: Here is a very closely related question on Retrocomputing: [Why did the PlayStation 2 implement backward compatibility that way?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13531/15988). It's not the same question, but provides a decent explanation